# how to get a form with 2 buttons posting to 2 different pages

Tags: forms

I would like to create a for to post some data which is a date to be chosen and there will be 2 buttons.

1 button needs to post the data on the same page and another button needs to post the data on a different page.

What I don't understand is how I can specify that in the 2 buttons as they are in the same form.

Thanks for your help,

John.

Comment: Use JavaScript and set the action accordingly..

Comment: ouch, could you please show me how to do it as I am not an expert in javascript but rather php and that won't do as it is server side :).

Comment: PHP can do that, use name on submit buttons, use if condition for redirects..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Do something like this with jQuery

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="jquery-1.9.1.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready(function(){
$("#first").click(function(){
$("#for").attr("action","ad.html");
$("#for").submit();
});
$("#second").click(function(){
$("#for").attr("action","test.html");
$("#for").submit();
});
});
</script>


<body>
<form id="for">

 input : <input type="text">

</form>
 <button id="first">Subit First</button><button id="second">Submit Second</button>
</body>
```

All the best